# How many 10-letter words do not contain all the vowels

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I can't find where I am overcounting in the problem

```
How many 10-letter words do not contain all the vowels.
```

What I do is to count all the words that have at least 5 different vowels:

$$
\binom{10}{5}5!*26^5,
$$

this means that I have the $5$ different vowels which can be fit in $10$ spaces. The rest of the word could be also a 5-letter word (no constriction imposed).

So the result should be:

$$
26^{10} - \binom{10}{5}5!*26^5.
$$

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Consider a word that has two $a$s, one of each of the other vowels, and four consonants: you’re counting it twice in $\binom{10}55!\cdot26^5$, once for each $a$ combined with the other four vowels. The word $aaeeiioouu$ is counted $2^5=32$ times in your calculation, once for each way of picking one of each vowel for the $\binom{10}5$ part.

Comment: As for how to approach the problem correctly, I recommend approaching via [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Count how many have no a's.  Count how many have no e's.... Count how many have no a's and no e's.  Count how many have no a's and no i's... Count how many have no a's e's i's o's or u's.

Comment: Actually this is the section which I am studying. But I don't know how to connect the problem with sets and formula (I) of the weblink.

Answer (score 2):

The question of "what is wrong with your count" has been answered above in the comments by @BrianM.Scott.  Here I begin the setup for the intended solution of the problem.

Let $N_a$ denote the event that there are no $a$'s in the word.  Let $N_e$ denote the event that there are no $e$'s in the word.  Etc. for the rest of the vowels.

Let our universal set, $S$, be all words that are of length ten (regardless of number of vowels present).

We have then $N_a^c$ represents the words of length ten which *do* have at least one $a$.

The number we are asked to calculate is $|N_a^c\cap N_e^c\cap N_i^c\cap N_o^c\cap N_u^c|$, in other words, the number of words which have at least one of each vowel.

Simplifying using DeMorgan's laws and inclusion exclusion, we have:

$\begin{array}{rl}|N_a^c\cap N_e^c\cap N_i^c\cap N_o^c\cap N_u^c| &= |S\setminus (N_a\cup N_e\cup N_i\cup N_o\cup N_u)| \\
&= |S| - |N_a\cup N_e\cup N_i\cup N_o\cup N_u|\\
&=|S|-|N_a|-|N_e|-|N_i|-\dots+|N_a\cap N_e|+\dots\\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~-|N_a\cap N_e\cap N_i|-\dots\end{array}$

Notice that $|N_a|=|N_e|=|N_i|=\dots$ and that $|N_a\cap N_e|=|N_a\cap N_i|=\dots$ etc. to simplify the above expression to:

$|S|-\binom{5}{1}|N_a|+\binom{5}{2}|N_a\cap N_e|-\binom{5}{3}|N_a\cap N_e\cap N_i|+\binom{5}{4}|N_a\cap N_e\cap N_i\cap N_o|-\binom{5}{5}|N_a\cap N_e\cap N_i\cap N_o\cap N_u|$

How big is something like $|N_a\cap N_e|$?

These are the words which simultaneously don't have $a$'s and don't have $e$'s.

> It is as though our alphabet has two fewer letters available.  Ten positions with twenty four options for each, we have $|N_a\cap N_e|=24^{10}$

Simplify all of the above terms similarly.

Comment: Ok this is were I came confused. The book says: Let $N_z$ be the set of ten letter words without a $z$. We want $|N_a \cup N_e \cup \dots \cup N_u|$. Is this equivalent to your answer?

Comment: Yes, they defined the sets in the same way I did.  The z they used was as s placeholder do they didn't have to write each set individually. There should also be the final step of removing that amount from the total.